# Share Extension to open containing app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios8-share-extension

I want to create an Android Style share feature for my app. 
I created a share extension which gets called when you select pictures inside the stock photo app and press share.
Now I want those pictures to be sent to the main app and get handled over there.
My question is now:

1. Can iOS open my app after a button is pressed on the share extension window?
2. How do I get the picture files inside my main app?

Comment: Here is a workaround solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73124182/14294561

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently there's no way to do this. A share extension cannot open the containing app.

The **intended** approach for share extensions is that they handle all of the necessary work themselves. Extensions can share code with their containing apps by using custom frameworks, so in most cases that's no problem.

If you want to make data available to your app, you can set up an app group so that you have a shared directory. The extension can write data there, and the app can read it. That won't happen until the next time the user launches the app, though.

Comment: Can a action extension open the app?

Comment: No. The only way an extension can open an app is if the app declares a custom URL scheme, and the extension uses `[NSExtensionContext openURL:error:]`. But on iOS, that method only works in today extensions, not in other extension types.

Comment: So what kind of extension is the "Copy to iBooks"? It appears in the share extension view whenever one tries to share a PDF. I've also seen other non Apple extensions with the same behavior. There has to be a way to make this work.

Comment: @TomHarrington it's an app that does exactly what you guys are saying it's impossible to do: https://itunes.apple.com/br/app/opener-open-links-in-apps/id989565871

Comment: The Truecaller app can do this, and it is using an action extension. The extension is invoked from the Phone app's recent call history - share contact. The extension launches, and the user can then click on a button in the extension's GUI, when they do then the Truecaller container app launches.

Comment: More Promising way http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228182/code-to-share-file-path-file-between-a-share-extension-and-ios-app

Comment: This is a common pattern for redirecting to the host app when the user has not authenticated. Download Tumblr and share a URL from Safari before logging in.

Answer (score 69):

**Swift 4+ (tested on iOS 13)**

`@objc` should be added to the declaration of `openURL`, that is,

```swift
@objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    // Code below.
}
```

Without it one would see this compiler error:

```
Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'openURL' that is not exposed to Objective-C
```

**Working solution in Swift 3.1 (tested in iOS10):**

*You need to create your own URL Scheme*, then add this function to your ViewController and call it with `openURL("myScheme://myIdentifier")`

```
//  Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
//  Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}
```

**Edit: Notes for clarification:**
`openURL` is a method of UIApplication - since your ShareExtension is not derived from UIApplication I added my own `openURL` with the same definition as the one from UIApplication to keep the compiler happy (so that *#selector(openURL(_:)* can be found).

Then I go through the responders until I find one that is really derived from `UIApplication` and call `openURL` on that.

More stripped-down-example-code which copies files in a ShareExtension to a local directory, serializing filenames and calling openURL on another app:

```
//
//  ShareViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import Social
import MobileCoreServices

class ShareViewController: UIViewController {

var docPath = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let containerURL = FileManager().containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.my-domain")!
    docPath = "\(containerURL.path)/share"
    
    //  Create directory if not exists
    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: docPath, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not create the directory \(error)")
    } catch {
        fatalError()
    }

    //  removing previous stored files
    let files = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docPath)
    for file in files {
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(docPath)/\(file)"))
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Export", message: " ", preferredStyle: .alert)
    
    self.present(alertView, animated: true, completion: {

        let group = DispatchGroup()
        
        NSLog("inputItems: \(self.extensionContext!.inputItems.count)")
        
            for item: Any in self.extensionContext!.inputItems {
                
            let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
            
            for provider: Any in inputItem.attachments! {
                
                let itemProvider = provider as! NSItemProvider
                group.enter()
                itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: kUTTypeData as String, options: nil) { data, error in
                    if error == nil {
                        //  Note: "data" may be another type (e.g. Data or UIImage). Casting to URL may fail. Better use switch-statement for other types.
                        //  "screenshot-tool" from iOS11 will give you an UIImage here
                        let url = data as! URL
                        let path = "\(self.docPath)/\(url.pathComponents.last ?? "")"
                        print(">>> sharepath: \(String(describing: url.path))")

                        try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: url, to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                        
                    } else {
                        NSLog("\(error)")
                    }
                    group.leave()
                }
            }
        }
        
        group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
            NSLog("done")
            
            let files = try! FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: self.docPath)
            
            NSLog("directory: \(files)")
            
            //  Serialize filenames, call openURL:
            do {
                let jsonData : Data = try JSONSerialization.data(
                    withJSONObject: [
                        "action" : "incoming-files"
                        ],
                    options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
                let jsonString = (NSString(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)! as String).addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
                let result = self.openURL(URL(string: "myapp://com.myapp.share?\(jsonString!)")!)
            } catch {
                alertView.message = "Error: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            }
            self.dismiss(animated: false) {
                self.extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
            }
        }
    })
}

//  Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
//  Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
@objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work in iOS 11 exactly. Problem is `openURL` is gone in favor of `open`, which has 3 params instead of 1. There's no way to use `perform` with 3 or more arguments, only 1 or 2 (I'm not kidding). So here's the alternative I'll try later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40533914/is-there-any-alternative-for-nsinvocation-in-swift

Comment: It definitely the best answer to this question, it works just fine for my app. But there is another problem, when my containing app is launched (not wake up from background) my my extension (actually its an Action Extension), my rootViewController is an EMPTY UIViewcontroller(not it's subclass), and a blank view appeared in my app.

Comment: This works nicely for me -- for clarity to anyone else, the `@objc func openURL...` should be in the `ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController`. I call this openURL func in the viewWillAppear of the ShareViewController and also call the self.shareExtension!.completeRequest code there too. This dismisses the share UI from photos or wherever immediately and launches your app.

Answer (score 10):

Technically you can't open containing app from share extension, but you can schedule local notification, and that's what I end up doing. Just before I call super.didSelectPost, I schedule local notification with some text, and if user wants to open containing app, they can, and if not - they can continue with their workflow. I even think its a better approach than automatically opening containing app and disrupting what they are doing.

Answer (score 5):

Implement custom url schema in host app and call openURL(url:) method

> like openURL(url:NSURL(string:"schema_name://"))

```
extension SLComposeServiceViewController {

    func openURL(url: NSURL) -> Bool {
        do {
            let application = try self.sharedApplication()
            return application.performSelector("openURL:", withObject: url) != nil
        }
        catch {
            return false
        }
    }

    func sharedApplication() throws -> UIApplication {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application
            }

            responder = responder?.nextResponder()
        }

        throw NSError(domain: "UIInputViewController+sharedApplication.swift", code: 1, userInfo: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to get this working by accessing the [shared `UIApplication` instance via key-value coding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53478538/446039) and calling `openURL` on that:

```swift
let application = UIApplication.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(UIApplication.shared)) as! UIApplication

let selector = NSSelectorFromString("openURL:")

let url = URL(string: "jptest://")!

application.perform(selector, with: url)
```

Comment: Apple explicitly says extensions are not allowed to use UIApplication. It may work, but there's a high chance Apple will reject the app.

Answer (score 4):

**Xamarin.iOS** version of @coyer answer:

```
using System;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using MobileCoreServices;
using CoreFoundation;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ObjCRuntime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Your.ShareExtension
{
public partial class ShareViewController : UIViewController
{
    public ShareViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    string docPath = "";

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        try
        {
            var containerURL = new NSFileManager().GetContainerUrl("group.com.qsiga.startbss");
            docPath = $"{containerURL.Path}/share";

            //  Create directory if not exists
            try
            {
                NSFileManager.DefaultManager.CreateDirectory(docPath, true, null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }

            //  removing previous stored files
            NSError contentError;
            var files = NSFileManager.DefaultManager.GetDirectoryContent(docPath, out contentError);
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                try
                {
                    NSError err;
                    NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Remove($"{docPath}/{file}", out err);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                { }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ShareViewController exception: " + e);
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidAppear(bool animated)
    {
        var alertView = UIAlertController.Create("Export", " ", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        PresentViewController(alertView, true, () =>
        {

            var group = new DispatchGroup();

            foreach (var item in ExtensionContext.InputItems)
            {

                var inputItem = item as NSExtensionItem;

                foreach (var provider in inputItem.Attachments)
                {

                    var itemProvider = provider as NSItemProvider;
                    group.Enter();
                    itemProvider.LoadItem(UTType.Data.ToString(), null, (data, error) =>
                                {
                                    if (error == null)
                                    {
                                        //  Note: "data" may be another type (e.g. Data or UIImage). Casting to URL may fail. Better use switch-statement for other types.
                                        //  "screenshot-tool" from iOS11 will give you an UIImage here
                                        var url = data as NSUrl;
                                        var path = $"{docPath}/{(url.PathComponents.LastOrDefault() ?? "")}";

                                        NSError err;
                                        NSFileManager.DefaultManager.Copy(url, NSUrl.CreateFileUrl(path, null), out err);
                                    }
                                    group.Leave();
                                });
                }
            }

            group.Notify(DispatchQueue.MainQueue, () =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "action", "incoming-files" } });
                    var jsonString = NSString.FromData(jsonData, NSStringEncoding.UTF8).CreateStringByAddingPercentEncoding(NSUrlUtilities_NSCharacterSet.UrlQueryAllowedCharacterSet);
                    var result = openURL(new NSUrl($"startbss://share?{jsonString}"));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    alertView.Message = $"Error: {e.Message}";
                }
                DismissViewController(false, () =>
                {
                    ExtensionContext?.CompleteRequest(new NSExtensionItem[] { }, null);
                });
            });
        });
    }

    public bool openURL(NSUrl url)
    {
        UIResponder responder = this;
        while (responder != null)
        {
            var application = responder as UIApplication;
            if (application != null)
                return CallSelector(application, url);

            responder = responder?.NextResponder;
        }
        return false;
    }

    [DllImport(Constants.ObjectiveCLibrary, EntryPoint = "objc_msgSend")]
    static extern bool _callSelector(
        IntPtr target,
        IntPtr selector,
        IntPtr url,
        IntPtr options,
        IntPtr completionHandler
    );

    private bool CallSelector(UIApplication application, NSUrl url)
    {
        Selector selector = new Selector("openURL:options:completionHandler:");

        return _callSelector(
            application.Handle,
            selector.Handle,
            url.Handle,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            IntPtr.Zero
        );
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I opened the host app from shared extension with a trick.
Using a webview with clear background color.
below is the code

```
 NSString *customURL = @"MY_HOST_URL_SCHEME_APP://";
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    webView.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [webView setOpaque:NO];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
    [webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [self didSelectCancel];
```

Comment: unfortunately it does not seem to work on iOS9 anymore :/  the webview delegate `- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView
shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
 navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType` will be called but neither `- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` nor `- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView` will, no error, just an ignored custom url :/

Answer (score 0):

Not only there is no way (and won't be) to do this:
there is no NEED to handle this in the app.
The extension is supposed to handle this with the very
same codebase as the main app. You should create a framework
with extension safe API shared between the app and the extesnion targets.

This is the top topic here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1

Extra rationale: in the extension you'd have to work with a much
smaller memory allowance meaning: if you use the images
of decent size as in the main app you will likely crash and burn.
In extension you'd have to work with jpeg or reasonable small size
and even then make sure size is small enough otherwise you'd be booted out trying to unpack the image from disk into memory
(see size limitation above)

Comment: Even using a common code base, extensions have a significantly lower memory allowance. I understand Apple wants everything to happen without leaving the app, however there are use cases where more memory is needed.

Comment: Batch jobs to the rescue. Extension spools them. Host application processes memory hungry jobs. Seriously, you comment has some merit. I just never run into the memory limitations (however stringent) for the extensions (that are meant to be simple and not burden the host app with lots of heap consumed)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem, and in iOS 11+ none of the previous answers work. I ended up adding a completion handler to my JavaScript code, and from there setting `window.location="myapp://"`. It's a bit hacky but it doesn't look to bad and the user can follow along.

Answer (score -6):

**EDIT: This solution works for today extension (Widget).**

An extension can open the hosting app:

```
- (IBAction)launchHostingApp:(id)sender
{
 NSURL *pjURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"hostingapp://home"];
[self.extensionContext openURL:pjURL completionHandler:nil];
}
```

And like Apple says in [Handling Commons Scenarios](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1)  :

An extension doesn’t directly tell its containing app to open; instead, it uses the openURL:completionHandler: method of NSExtensionContext to tell the system to open its containing app. When an extension uses this method to open a URL, the system validates the request before fulfilling it.

Comment: The `openURL:completionHandler:` method only works in a "today" extension, not in a share extension.