# Redirect back to app from Share Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios8-share-extension

Is it possible to redirect a user back to my app from my [share extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html) (after finishing the posting/other action)?

I couldn't get `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` to work - method was unavailable.

Any ideas if this is possible/if Apple even allows it?

Comment: What share extension are you using? Is it `UIActivityViewController` or you have created your custom?

Comment: share extension, as in a separate target - and it is the Share Extension. Here is a link for reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share Extension to open Host App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506413/share-extension-to-open-host-app)

Answer (score 2):

Actually this is possible by searching for UIApplication up in the responder chain and invoking `openURL` on it, like described in this response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28037297/554203.

This is the code that works for XCode 8, Swift 3.0 and iOS10 (again, extracted from Julio Bailon's response above):

```
let url = NSURL(string:urlString)
let context = NSExtensionContext()
context.open(url! as URL, completionHandler: nil)

var responder = self as UIResponder?

while (responder != nil){
    if responder?.responds(to: Selector("openURL:")) == true{
        responder?.perform(Selector("openURL:"), with: url)
    }
    responder = responder!.next
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of iOS 9.3, this does not seem to be possible for a `Share Extension`.

Comment: this should be in comment section not in the answer.