# Xamarin-iOS: host application will not run with share extension

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

My app setup is a basic new app with default viewController with the default classes for share extension on iOS 11.2.
The host AppDelegate class FinishedLaunching never gets called.
Just shows the launch screen and closes the app.

The sample Xamarin app provided also has the same issue.
Link to the sample app:
[Share Extension sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/ios8/Share/)

Any idea whats going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to open the app which you created with the share extension, when user clicks the share button to use this share extension? If so, this app should be called **Containing App**.

But unfortunately, there's no way to do this on iOS8.3+ except `Today Extension`. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27517554/8354952) we know that:

> The intended approach for share extensions is that they handle all of
>   the necessary work themselves.

Also from the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionCreation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH5-SW1) about extension:

> An extension’s UI should be simple, restrained, and focused on
>   facilitating a single task.

Apple doesn't recommend us to open its containing app from extensions, actually it avoids that. If you want to retrieve data in containing app, you can set up an app group so that data can be shared between these two apps.

Comment: Not really, the Containing App won't run at all.
But  found that was the case only on simulators. Now all is working fine.
Thanks