# Is there any way to open host app from share extension?

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

Duplicate link: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506413/share-extension-to-open-containing-app)

I’ve followed the above link, but it’s not working.

**My Procedure**: I’ve created a url scheme for host app and called OpenURL for launching host app from share extension.
**(Swift 5, Tested on iOS 13, Xcode 11.3)**

```
func openURL(url: URL) {
   var responder: UIResponder? = self
   while responder != nil {
       if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            application.perform(#selector(openURL(url:)), with: url)
            return
       }
       responder = responder?.next
   } 
}
```

I've used the above method inside SLComposeServiceViewController, called openURL(URL(string: "MyHostAppScheme://")) within this controller. But it's not possible to open Host app from this share extension app.

I've searched Apple [forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/114485), but didn't get any solution.

**Note:** I've found an app from AppStore which is capable to open app from share extension.

Your Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

This is not allowed by Apple company.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27295