# iOS shareExtension is not availible for all types WebContents

Tags: ios, swift, share-extension

I am working on a shareExtension for an app which should consume share-links from Spotify & Apple Music. I have set `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount` and `NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount` to 1 in the Info.plist.

When I am trying to share a song from Spotify/ Apple Music, my extension is in the List of availible targets. When I am trying to share a playlist, it does not show up.

I tried to allow other "supporting" types like file attachments or images, but it did not work.

Any suggesstions what to look out for?

**My current Info.plist**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsMovieWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsFileWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>100</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
        <string>ShareViewController</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**My current ShareViewController.swift**

```swift
@objc(ShareViewController)
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

    let URL_TYPE = "public.url"
    let TEXT_TYPE = "public.text"
    let SHARED_SUITE_NAME = "xxx"
    var rootView: ShareView?
    var playlists: DtoPlaylists?
    var shareURL: DtoShareURL?

    override func isContentValid() -> Bool {
        // Do validation of contentText and/or NSExtensionContext attachments here
        return true
    }

    override func configurationItems() -> [Any]! {
        // To add configuration options via table cells at the bottom of the sheet, return an array of SLComposeSheetConfigurationItem here.
        return []
    }

    /**
     * Called after the controller's view is loaded into memory
     */
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .clear

        self.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen

        initSwiftUIView()
    }

    /**
     * Notifies the view controller that its view is about to be added to a view hierarchy
     - Parameter animated: If true, the view is being added to the window using an animation
     */
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        _ = updatePlaylistsFromDefaults()

        let extensionItem = extensionContext?.inputItems[0] as! NSExtensionItem
        for attachment in extensionItem.attachments! {
            if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(TEXT_TYPE) {
                attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: TEXT_TYPE, options: nil, completionHandler: { (results, error) in
                    if let sharedText = results as! String? {
                        self.shareURL?.shareURL = sharedText
                    }
                })
            } else if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier(URL_TYPE) {
                attachment.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: URL_TYPE, options: nil, completionHandler: { (results, error) in
                    if let sharedURL = results as! URL? {
                        self.shareURL?.shareURL = sharedURL.absoluteString
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func cancelAction() {
        let error = NSError(domain: "xxx", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: "User aborted request"])
        extensionContext?.cancelRequest(withError: error)
    }

    /**
     * renders the SwiftUI view and attatches it to the viewStack
     */
    private func initSwiftUIView() {
        let decodedPlaylist = updatePlaylistsFromDefaults()

        playlists = DtoPlaylists.init(playlists: decodedPlaylist)
        // TODO remove this placeholder
        shareURL = DtoShareURL.init(shareURL: "PLACEHOLDER")
        rootView = ShareView(closeAction: cancelAction, submit: didSelectPost, playlists: playlists!, shareURL: shareURL!, persistPlaylistInApp: persistPlaylistInApp)
        let controller = UIHostingController(rootView: rootView)
        controller.view.backgroundColor = .blue
        addChild(controller)
        controller.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(controller.view)
        controller.didMove(toParent: self)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            controller.view.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            controller.view.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1.0),
            controller.view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            controller.view.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    private func updatePlaylistsFromDefaults() -> [DtoPlaylist] {
        let defaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: SHARED_SUITE_NAME)
        var decodedPlaylist: [DtoPlaylist] = []
        let savedPlaylists = defaults!.data(forKey: "playlists")
        if savedPlaylists != nil {
            decodedPlaylist = try! JSONDecoder().decode([DtoPlaylist].self, from: savedPlaylists!)
        }
        return decodedPlaylist
    }

    override func didSelectPost() {
//         TODO is this method still needed?
    }

    /**
     * Opens the main app with a specific shareURL so the main app can import that
     */
    private func persistPlaylistInApp(shareURL: String) {
        // TODO remove example
        // TODO make sure to encode shareURL
        let url = URL(string: "xxx://APPLE_MUSIC?pl.2cc9c5f8896546ea9908743222a6d5fb")
        _ = openURL(url!)
    }

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499222/13130130
    // Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
    // Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
    @objc func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
        var responder: UIResponder? = self
        while responder != nil {
            if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
                return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
            }
            responder = responder?.next
        }
        return false
    }


}
```

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same issue. My app shows up for Spotify, but not for Apple Music playlist. If I share an Apple Music playlist with Mail, it just has a URL in there.

Answer (score 0):

In principle what happens when you try to share a file from an app is tgat the system will look for all apps that can handle that kind of file. The system will launch your `ShareExtension` which will process the input.

That means you have to make sure that your `ShareExtension`'s `NSExtensionActivationRule` in the info.plist includes the required value.
You could try adding `NSExtensionActivationSupportsText` as this should cover everything in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    <key>NSExtension</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
        <dict>
            <!--Version 2 means we only have to match one (not all) of the things in the shared attachment-->
            <key>NSExtensionActivationDictionaryVersion</key>
            <integer>2</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationUsesStrictMatching</key>
            <false/>
            <!--Had to put Max Count 3 in order for Apple Music playlist sharing to work-->             <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
            <true/>
            <!--Had to put Max Count 3 in order for Apple Music playlist sharing to work-->             <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsAttachmentsWithMaxCount</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```