How to resolve "Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'openURL' in a synchronous nonisolated context; this is an error in Swift 6"
currently, I am getting
Call to main actor-isolated instance method 'openURL' in a synchronous nonisolated context; this is an error in Swift 6

warning in
self.openURL(url)

Do you have any idea how I can resolve such? Here is the code snippet.
Thanks.
@MainActor
private func shareAndBye(url: String) {
    self.extensionContext?.completeRequest(returningItems: nil, completionHandler: { _ in
        if let encodedURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
            let appURL = "melonote://share?url=" + encodedURL
            guard let url = URL(string: appURL) else { return }
            _ = self.openURL(url)
        }
    })
}

// Courtesy: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44499222/13363449 
// Function must be named exactly like this so a selector can be found by the compiler!
// Anyway - it's another selector in another instance that would be "performed" instead.
@objc private func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
    var responder: UIResponder? = self
    while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
            return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
        }
        responder = responder?.next
    }
    return false
}

Here is the complete code snippet if you are interested
https://gist.github.com/yccheok/cf7358a2f8a813da290ab36240f81c52
Thanks.

I would bridge completeRequest to Swift Concurrency - make it async using a continuation. By making it async, the code in the completion handler can hop back onto the main actor.
Add a method like this in the view controller,
@discardableResult
private func completeRequestAsync(returningItems items: [Any]?) async -> Bool? {
    guard let extensionContext else { return nil }
    return await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        extensionContext.completeRequest(returningItems: items) {
            continuation.resume(returning: $0)
        }
    }
}

Then make shareAndBye to async too, so that you can call the above method.
private func shareAndBye(url: String) async {
    await completeRequestAsync(returningItems: nil)
    if let encodedURL = url.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) {
        let appURL = "melonote://share?url=" + encodedURL
        guard let url = URL(string: appURL) else { return }
        _ = self.openURL(url)
    }
}

From the gist, you seem to be calling shareAndBye from a Task { ... } already, so you just need to add the word await to the call and that's it.
