Issue with Share Component using Expo and React
I'm trying to implement sharing from the gallery for my app and using the following component
https://ajith-ab.github.io/react-native-receive-sharing-intent
It works great with android but I'm getting an error with ios quite difficult to solve:
in AppDelegate.mm
I have
    // Linking API
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options {
  return [super application:application openURL:url options:options] || [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}

In ShareViewController.swift
I have
  private func redirectToHostApp(type: RedirectType) {
   let url = URL(string: "\(shareProtocol)://dataUrl=\(sharedKey)#\(type)")
   var responder = self as UIResponder?
   let selectorOpenURL = sel_registerName("openURL:")
   
   while (responder != nil) {
     if (responder?.responds(to: selectorOpenURL))! {
       let _ = responder?.perform(selectorOpenURL, with: url)
     }
     responder = responder!.next
   }
   extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
 }

But I'm getting the following error:
BUG IN CLIENT OF UIKIT: The caller of UIApplication.openURL(_:) needs to migrate to the non-deprecated UIApplication.open(_:options:completionHandler:). Force returning false (NO).

Is something deprecated?
Any tip to rewrite it?
I've tried a solution found here
Share Extension to open containing app
and adapted mu function like bellow
  private func redirectToHostApp(type: RedirectType) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(shareProtocol)://dataUrl=\(sharedKey)#\(type)")
    
    if url != nil {
      var responder = self as UIResponder?
      
      while responder != nil {
        if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
          if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
            application.open(url!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
          } else {
            application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url)
          }
        }
        responder = responder?.next
      }
    }
    extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
  }

and getting then the error
Failed to open URL ShareMedia://dataUrl=ShareKey#media: Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-10814 "(null)" UserInfo={_LSLine=279, _LSFunction=-[_LSDOpenClient openURL:fileHandle:options:completionHandler:]}

Not quite sure how to troubleshoot from this point
Thanks for any direction you can provide

Looks like a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506413/share-extension-to-open-containing-app/78975759#78975759 but can't really adapt my code to the solutions provided.

I've eventually managed to fix it using
  @objc @discardableResult private func openURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool {
      var responder: UIResponder? = self
      while responder != nil {
          if let application = responder as? UIApplication {
              if #available(iOS 18.0, *) {
                if application.canOpenURL(url) {
                  application.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                  return true
                } else {
                  return false;
                }

              } else {
                  return application.perform(#selector(openURL(_:)), with: url) != nil
              }
          }
          responder = responder?.next
      }
      return false
  }
  
  private func redirectToHostApp(type: RedirectType) {
    let url = URL(string: "\(shareProtocol)://dataUrl=\(sharedKey)#\(type)")
    openURL(url!)
    extensionContext!.completeRequest(returningItems: [], completionHandler: nil)
  }

but the share protocol must be the hostAppBundleIdentifier for some reason.
